# Is it possible to bind parameters to stored procedure in MYSQLi?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I've been reading up on Stored Procedures & MYSQLi from here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

and other sources, but am still unsure how to call a stored procedure with `?` (like a prepared statement)

**Is it possible to bind parameters to a stored procedure, in something similiar to this:**

```
$mysqli->query("CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN id_var INT) BEGIN INSERT INTO test(id)
         VALUES(id_var); END;"))
$mysqli->bindParam("i", $some_int);
$mysqli->query("CALL p");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding parameters is a PHP-side operation; stored procedures are a MySQL thing. The two are not related and should not be treated as such.

With prepared statements and parameter-binding, you define a query using the `prepare()` method, then bind values into the `?`s using `bind_param()`. So given your example, a prepared-statements approach would look like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $some_int);
$stmt->execute();
```

On the other hand, with a stored procedure, you simply call it [using the `CALL` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html) as a normal query:

```
//procedure created beforehand
CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN id_var INT)
INSERT INTO test (id)
VALUES (id_var);
//now in PHP:
$mysqli->query("CALL p($some_int)");
```

I'm not certain if you can run a `CREATE PROCEDURE` using the `query()` method.

So to answer your question: yes, it is possible to use both at the same time (because they are different things), but not in the way that you're imagining, and it would be redundant.

Comment: in `$mysqli->query("CALL p($some_int)");` would the values need to be escaped before passing them through?

Comment: Yes, because that is not a prepared statement. However, the procedure definition *does* declare `id_var` as an `INT`, so if you tried to enter in characters it would most likely fail.

Comment: If you get `$some_int` from user input you still need to make sure it's an int, otherwise you can easily get `0); DROP TABLE etc...--` string as input...