# using STORED PROCEDURES: different results in mysqli->query("CALL select_procedure") VS mysqli->query("SELECT ...")

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am migrating all my mysqli queries to STORED PROCEDURE. 
It should be as easy as changing one line in the mysqli call, howver, the two following codes give different results:

Regular query, which works correctly:

```
$query = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM user
                                   WHERE 
                                   MATCH (name) AGAINST ('* *$sanitized* *') ");

if ($query) {   
  $nrows = $query -> num_rows;
  if ($nrows > 0) {
      $searchResult = 'We found '. $nrows .' results';
  }
}
```

CALL to PROCEDURE, which returns a "fetch_array() on boolean" error:

```
$query = $this->mysqli->query("CALL myfunction('.$sanitized.')");
```

where the procedures is defined as:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myfunction (sanitized VARCHAR(124))
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM user
                                   WHERE 
                                   MATCH (name) AGAINST ('* *sanitized* *');
END 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I can't find a solution and it seems that no one has a similar issue in this forum.

Comment: I added the PHP page due to the title, and a delete or edited comment saying something did or didn't work via `mysqli`

Comment: My mistake. I added the `mysql` tag 2 hours ago. Finally just added the `php` tag now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) used with [`concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) as they often are.

```
DROP PROCEDURE if exists myStoredProc101;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProc101
(   pSanitized VARCHAR(124)
)
BEGIN
    set @mySql:=concat("SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM user where match(name) against ('* *",pSanitized,"* *')");
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @mySql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Your stored proc had no chance of working as it wasn't even using your parameter. What you did was bury something inside of a string literal. Also, varchar(124) is a bit odd :p

About the only success people have with prepared statements is with using a User Variable (with an `@`) versus failed attempts of using Local Variables (from DECLARE). So, that may save you a few hours of head banging in the future.

From the PHP Manual Page [Stored Procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.html):

> *Handling result sets*
>
> Stored procedures can return result sets. Result sets returned from a
>   stored procedure cannot be fetched correctly using mysqli_query. The
>   mysqli_query function combines statement execution and fetching the
>   first result set into a buffered result set, if any. However, there
>   are additional stored procedure result sets hidden from the user which
>   cause mysqli_query to fail returning the user expected result sets.
>
> Result sets returned from a stored procedure are fetched using
>   mysqli_real_query or mysqli_multi_query. Both functions allow fetching
>   any number of result sets returned by a statement, such as CALL.
>   Failing to fetch all result sets returned by a stored procedure causes
>   an error.

As for calling the stored proc from `mysqli`, please take a look at the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28970545) from Pablo Tobar. It does not look especially pleasant with many variables, but that seems to be where it is at. Spoiler Alert: use mysql variables, not PHP variables.

Granted, Pablo was not returning a resultset, but rather writing to an `OUT` var in the stored proc. Perhaps you need to do what he did for the `IN` parameters, and call `multi_query()`, then a `store_result()`, then a `fetch_all()` (in short, the PHP reference a page up).

Alternatively, a call would be made as done by Palladium [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11785021).

In either case, case must be taken to avoid the known vulnerability of passing **SQL Injection** over to stored procedure routines.

Comment: I found a reference to `mysqli` and result sets from stored procs. Do you need to see it? Edit: edit performed to answer

Comment: Hi @Drew, I've been rewriting and testing my procedure based on your suggestions. The procedure contains way more statements than those above and I've finally got it to work. 
However, yes, please, send me what you found about fetching with multi_query because I've not been able to do it so far when applied to the current $query returned by my procedure above. thanks.

Comment: I added the block at the bottom where it says "From the PHP Manual ..." . But feel free to somehow get your code out there or ...

Comment: post it or a small snippet in the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) room

Comment: the correct syntax for multi_query based on the php manual is
`if($this->mysqli->multi_query($query))`
but it complains that my $query (see above) cannot be passed multi_query

Comment: `var_dump($query)` returns the same whether I obtain $query from the regular query or from the STORED PROCEDURE. this means that the two `$query` should be the same. I don't understand then why `$result = $query ->fetch_assoc()` only works when $query is not coming from the PROCEDURE.

Comment: I was chatting away with you (alone) in Campaigns